How can I decrease model files generated by OpenAPI Generator using jaxrs-resteasy?
I would like to decrease the amount of DTO model files generated by OpenAPI Generator using jaxrs-resteasy. Currently it's generating 10 files and I only have 4 component schemas in my OAS (3.0).
The other files are from the responses schemas and it's giving me, e.g., playersIdDelete200Response.java and playersIdDelete400Response.java, both for the same operation (DELETE /players/{email}) and I don't want this.
What I want is to have the minimum (possible) of model generated files just to keep it simple.
I have tags in my OAS and each corresponding operation.
I've used the following plugin configuration
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.9.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/docusign-ui-webdav-1.0-swagger.json
            </inputSpec>
            <generatorName>jaxrs-resteasy</generatorName>
            <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/.openapi-generator-ignore
            </ignoreFileOverride>
            <configOptions>
                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                <implFolder>src/gen/java/main</implFolder>
                <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            </configOptions>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

Currently, I'm having these fictional namespaces for the 10 generated DTO files.

Players
Referees
Fields
PlayersInner
FieldsInnersPlayers
RefereesEmailDelete200Response
RefereesEmailDelete400Response
PlayersEmailDelete200Response
RefereesInnerFields
FieldsInnerReferees

I've tried <usingTags>, but it doesn't seem to work, and I keep getting the same 10 files.
